# UPS network shutdown for Synology and ESXi, USB UPS

Tags: vmware-esxi, synology, ups

I have had a USB UPS for a while now and although I've never had a power outage with it and my Synology NAS, in testing it's worked great connected just with USB to the NAS. Now I've added an ESXi node that uses the NAS for storage. So in the event of a power outage, the VMs need to shutdown, then the ESXi and Synology can shutdown together or in order.

I've tried [this](https://medium.com/@mattwebbio/shutting-down-esxi-6-7-with-a-ups-connected-to-freenas-11-2a270c129dbc) already but got stuck at enabling community supported packages cause I installed ESXi with secure boot enabled.

So what are my options and what's best practice? I could reinstall ESXi and use NUTclient, or write my own thing to login into ESXi over ssh and shut down that way. Other ideas?

Comment: I suspect this is one of those areas that didn't receive a lot of attention over the years. Personally, I would have an appropriate endpoint of your preference setup (Windows/Linux), connect that to the UPS, and it can run scripts to initiate the shutdowns (either PowerCLI or native in-guest actions).

Comment: Thoughts on setting up every guest to shut down themselves and then just letting the power cut off on esxi?